# zsh: reuse all arguments from previous command

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, arguments

In `zsh`, the key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> is bound to `insert-last-word`, and it will insert the last argument from previous command on the current command line.

I am looking for a keybinding / shortcut that will act similar to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, except that it will paste all the arguments from previous command on the command line .

I know I can type `!*` and zsh will interpret it as "reuse all arguments from previous command". But this is not quite what I am looking for. Also, it does not actually paste the arguments so that I can see them, zsh only interprets `!*` as such. I could hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to have it expanded, but that is yet another command necessary.

I would prefer to have this as a key combination such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>something</kbd>, instead of having to type '!*' and hitting tab

How can I do this ?

## UPDATE

After using the widget extensively for few years, I found few things that bother me: (I have the widget bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>)

1. it works OK once, but when I repeat again, it cycles through my zsh history from the beginning of my `.zsh_history` file.

Instead, I would like the widget to go backwards, from most recent history to the beginning.

2. again, when it cycles from the beginning of my zsh history, the space between the command, and the arguments-to-be-completed is removed.

ie:

type some command with arguments:

```
echo 111 222 333
```

use widget to complete arguments from previous command:

```
printf <WIDGET>
printf 111 222 333
```

above works as expected. But when I press WIDGET again, it suddenly behaves like this:

```
printf <WIDGET>
printf111 222 333
```

ie the space between command and argumens was removed

3. lastly, I would like to bind another key, for instance <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> to do the reverse, so that when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> one too many times, I can go back one step.

Comment: Note that `!*` expands to all but the first **token** from the previous history entry, not _all arguments from previous command_. If the previous entry was `(echo foo; echo bar)`, `!*` expands to `echo foo; echo bar)` not `bar`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To insert all but the first *word* of the previous history entry, you could define a custom widget like:

```
insert-last-words() {
  emulate -L zsh
  set -o extendedglob # for the # wildcard operator

  local direction
  case $WIDGET in
    (*-reverse) direction=-1;;
    (*) direction=1;;
  esac

  if [[ ${WIDGET%-reverse} = ${LASTWIDGET%-reverse} ]]; then
    # subsequent invocations go further back in history like
    # insert-last-word

    (($+INSERT_LAST_WORDS_SKIP_UNDO)) ||
      NUMERIC=1 zle undo # previous invocation

    # we honour $NUMERIC for Alt+4 Alt+/ to go back 4 in history
    ((INSERT_LAST_WORDS_INDEX += ${NUMERIC-1} * direction))
  else
    # head of history upon first invocation
    INSERT_LAST_WORDS_INDEX=0
  fi
  unset INSERT_LAST_WORDS_SKIP_UNDO

  local lastwords
  local cmd=${history:$INSERT_LAST_WORDS_INDEX:1}

  # cmdline split according to zsh tokenisation rules
  lastwords=(${(z)cmd})

  if (($#lastwords <= 1)); then
    # return failure (causing beep or visual indication) when the
    # corresponding cmd had no arguments. We also need to remember
    # not to undo next time.
    INSERT_LAST_WORDS_SKIP_UNDO=1
    return 1
  fi

  # remove first word (preserving spacing between the remaining
  # words).
  cmd=${cmd##[[:space:]]#$lastwords[1][[:space:]]#}
  LBUFFER+=$cmd
}

zle -N insert-last-words
zle -N insert-last-words-reverse insert-last-words
bindkey '\e/' insert-last-words
bindkey '\e\\' insert-last-words-reverse
```

Comment: the widget works perfectly

Comment: I have updated the original question with description of the issues I am having, and created a bounty.

Comment: @MartinVegter, see edit.

Comment: works perfectly now. Thank you very much.